# Make layout clickable

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In my app I have several fragments with different `ListView`s, but for all them I want to use the same empty view, so I created a separate layout with the empty view and added it to the other layouts using

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    layout="@layout/empty_view"/>
```

Everything works as expected but now I'm trying to make that view clickable so I can reload `ListView` when the user taps on the empty view, however I can't make it work. Any idea on how to do it?

This is what I have tried so far:

(empty_view.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/error_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#929292"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="@string/empty_list_error"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        layout="@layout/empty_view"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner_filter"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white_90pct"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="@string/subject_indicator"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/light_color"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/white_90pct"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="@string/grade_indicator"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/semesters_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_header"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java class (onCreateView)

```
LinearLayout emptyView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
emptyView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I also tried adding the next attributes to the xml but still not working:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: try giving clickListener to the individual items and check, like 
`LinearLayout emptyView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
emptyView.findViewById(R.id.emptyTextView).setOnClickListener(this);
emptyView.findViewById(R.id.emptyImageView).setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: @Antrromet, I kinda wanna avoid that, cos then I'd need to add more listeners in case I add more views to the empty view layout. That's why I want to make the whole view clickable

Comment: under `android:clickable="true"` on your listview, set `android:onClick="test"`. then in your code create the method `test(View v){ }` and see if that gets called. (put something inside it and breakpoint). Plus remove any coded listeners for this test

Comment: I tested your code and found that it works; my breakpoint in `onClick` is hit.  Also, when you call `setOnClickListener()`, according to the documentation, the ViewGroup becomes clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`emptyView.setOnTouchListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener))

Are you including `empty_view` into another view that blocks descendant focusability?

**Since your edit**

Your ListView is on top of the empty_view and blocking clickability.

Comment: I edited my question and added the full layout of the fragment where I use the empty view. Can you take check is there's anything wrong? Did you test the code adding the empty view as `<include layout=:"@layout/empty_layout">`?

Comment: I did test that way, but I had no other view **below** empty_view in XML.  Siblings are added on top of one another the further down XML you go.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already specified the `linearlayout` to be `clickable`, you just need to specify the method for the `onClick` event.

So add you your linearLayouts xml, the `onClick` attribute as below:  (`focusable` may be needed too)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:onClick="layoutClicked"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:gravity="center">
```

Then in your code have the method to go with it

```
 public void layoutClicked(View v)
 {
       // Your code here
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as providing the default `OnClickListener`? Anyway, I tried it but didn't work. Do you think it has anything to do with the fact that the empty view layout is not part of the original layout? as I said, it's added to the main layout using `<include layout=:"@layout/empty_layout">`

Answer (score 0):

Since your empty view fills its parent, make sure your include tag for your empty view is the last in the other layout so it will be top-most in the z-order.

Comment: You are right! Apparently something was blocking it, I moved the layout to the bottom of the xml file and that solved it! Thanks a lot!